# linkedlist implementation in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have tried to implement a linkedlist in `java` using a `Node` class,and keeping only a single link to the beginning of the linkedlist (lets call it 'first').

I need to take care of 2 cases-

1.when the linkedlist is empty -in which case I need to create a new Node at 'first'

2.when there are Nodes in the linkedlist

I tried to code it as below..but I am wondering if this is the standard way ..The code block handling the first case looks a bit ugly..

What is the standard way to do this?

```
public class MyLList<Item>{
    Node first;

    public  void insertAtBeginning(Item item){
        Node old = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = old;
    }

    public void insertAtEnd(Item item){
        Node t = first;
        while(t!=null && t.next!=null){
            t=t.next;
        }

        if(t==null){
            first = new Node();
            first.item = item;
            return;
        }
        Node old = t;
        t = new Node();
        t.item = item;
        old.next = t;
    }

    public void traverse(){
        for(Node x=first;x!=null;x=x.next){
            System.out.print(x.item+" ");
        }
    }

    private class Node{
        Item item;
        Node next;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyLList<String> ll = new MyLList<String>();

        ll.insertAtEnd("X");
        ll.insertAtBeginning("B");
        ll.insertAtEnd("Y");
        ll.traverse();

    }

}
```

Comment: what is the correct way ? should the Node be defined as Node<Item> ?

Comment: I take back what I said, I didn't look at your code precisely enough and posted a wrong comment.

Comment: I think the Node class should be a generic class just like the containing class. By the way, [Oracle recommends](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) using a single uppercase letter as a generic type name. It can be useful to follow these conventions.

Comment: @Tamás: The node class is a private inner class of `MyLList`, so it can use the generic type of `MyLList`, and doesn't need to be generic itself.

Comment: @jlordo: Yes, you are right. To be honest, I wasn't sure whether the inner class can use the generic type of the containing class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it to more clear:

```
public void insertAtEnd(Item item){
    if (first == null)
        insertAtBeginning(Item item);
    else{
        Node t = first;
        while(t!=null && t.next!=null){
            t=t.next;
        }

        Node old = t;
        t = new Node();
        t.item = item;
        old.next = t;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Dear Damon, you did the thing right. Nothing ugly. The solution of Antonio is just a bit more... elegant I would say.

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty node representing the root of your linked-list, that will remove the need for special handling of "root is null" case.

Something like this:

```
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        MyLList<String> ll = new MyLList<String>();

        ll.insertAtEnd("X");
        ll.insertAtBeginning("B");
        ll.insertAtEnd("Y");
        ll.Traverse();

    }

    public class MyLList<Item>
    {
        Node first = new Node();

        public void insertAtBeginning(Item item)
        {
            Node oldFirst = first.next;

            first.next = new Node();
            first.next.item = item;
            first.next.next = oldFirst;
        }

        public void insertAtEnd(Item item)
        {
            Node tail = first;
            while (tail.next != null)
            {
                tail = tail.next;
            }

            tail.next = new Node();
            tail.next.item = item;
        }

        public void traverse()
        {
            for (Node x = first.next; x != null; x = x.next)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(x.item + " ");
            }
        }

        private class Node
        {
            public Item item;
            public Node next;
        }



    }
```

Comment: It did not bother about the generics stuff, just the linked list question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Linked List Program with following functionalities

1. Insert at Begining

2. Insert at End

3. Insert at any position

4. Delete at Position

5. Get Size

6. Display

7. Empty Status

8. Replace data at given position

9. Get Element by Position

10. Search Element Recursively

11. Swap only data not node

12. Swap node for given data

13. Reverse the list

14. Find Middle Element

15. Count Occurrence of a Number








    import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class Node<T> {

        Node<T> next = null;
        T data;

        Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

    class LinkedList<T> {

        Node<T> head = null;
        Node<T> last = null;

        public LinkedList() {
            head = null;
            last = null;
        }

        public void insertAtFirst(T data) {
            Node<T> nptr = new Node<T>(data);
            if (head == null) {
                head = nptr;
                last = head;
            } else {
                nptr.next = head;
                head = nptr;
            }
            display(head);
        }

        public void insertAtLast(T data) {
            Node<T> nptr = new Node<T>(data);
            if (empty()) {
                head = nptr;
                last = nptr;
            } else {
                last.next = nptr;
                last = nptr;
            }
            display(head);
        }

        public void insertAtPosition(int position, T data) {
            if (empty()) {
                insertAtFirst(data);
                return;
            }

            Node<T> headPtr = head;
            position -= 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < size(); i++) {
                if (position == i) {
                    Node<T> nptr = new Node<T>(data);
                    Node<T> temp = headPtr.next;
                    headPtr.next = nptr;
                    nptr.next = temp;
                    break;
                }
                headPtr = headPtr.next;
            }
            display(head);
        }

        public void delete(int position) {
            if (empty())
                throw new NoSuchElementException("List is Empty!");

            if (position == 1) {
                if (head.next == null) {
                    head = null;
                } else {
                    Node<T> temp = head.next;
                    head = temp;
                }
                display(head);
                return;
            }

            if (position == size()) {
                Node<T> headPtr = head;
                Node<T> lastPtr = headPtr;
                while (headPtr.next != null) {
                    lastPtr = headPtr;
                    headPtr = headPtr.next;
                }
                lastPtr.next = null;
                last = lastPtr;
                display(head);
                return;
            }

            Node<T> startPtr = head;
            position -= 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < size(); i++) {
                if (i == position) {
                    Node<T> temp = startPtr.next;
                    temp = temp.next;
                    startPtr.next = temp;
                }
                startPtr = startPtr.next;
            }
            display(head);
        }

        public void display(Node<T> link) {
            if (link != null) {
                System.out.print(link.data + " ");
                display(link.next);
            }
        }

        public int size() {
            if (empty())
                throw new NoSuchElementException("List is Empty");

            Node<T> headPtr = head;
            int count = 1;
            while (headPtr.next != null) {
                count++;
                headPtr = headPtr.next;
            }
            return count;
        }

        public void replace(int position, T data) {
            if (empty())
                throw new NoSuchElementException("List is Empty!");

            Node<T> startPtr = head;
            for (int i = 1; i < size(); i++) {
                if (i == position) {
                    startPtr.data = data;
                    break;
                }
                startPtr = startPtr.next;
            }
            display(head);
        }

        public T elementByPosition(int position, Node<T> link, int count) {
            if (count == position) {
                return link.data;
            }
            return elementByPosition(position, link.next, ++count);
        }

        public int searchElement(T data, Node<T> link, int position) {
            if (empty())
                throw new NoSuchElementException("List is Empty!");

            if (link.data == data)
                return position;

            return searchElement(data, link.next, ++position);
        }

        public Node<T> getLinkByData(T data, Node<T> link) {
            if (link == null)
                return link;

            if (link.data == data)
                return link;

            return getLinkByData(data, link.next);
        }

        public void swapData(T firstData, T secondData) {
            if (empty())
                throw new NoSuchElementException("List is Empty!");

            Node<T> firstDataLink = getLinkByData(firstData, head);
            Node<T> secondDataLink = getLinkByData(secondData, head);
            if (firstDataLink == null || secondDataLink == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Eithe " + firstData + " or " + secondData + " not in the list");
            }
            firstDataLink.data = secondData;
            secondDataLink.data = firstData;
            display(head);
        }

        public void swapNode(T firstData, T secondData) {

            if (empty())
                throw new NoSuchElementException("List is Empty!");

            if (firstData == secondData)
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Can't swap for identical data");

            boolean foundFirstData = false;
            boolean foundSecondData = false;

            Node<T> firstDataPtr = head;
            Node<T> prevFirstDataPtr = head;
            while (firstDataPtr.next != null && !(firstDataPtr.data == firstData)) {
                prevFirstDataPtr = firstDataPtr;
                firstDataPtr = firstDataPtr.next;
            }
            if (firstDataPtr.data == firstData)
                foundFirstData = true;

            Node<T> secondDataPtr = head;
            Node<T> prevSecondDataPtr = head;
            while (secondDataPtr.next != null && !(secondDataPtr.data == secondData)) {
                prevSecondDataPtr = secondDataPtr;
                secondDataPtr = secondDataPtr.next;
            }
            if (secondDataPtr.data == secondData)
                foundSecondData = true;

            if (foundFirstData && foundSecondData) {

                // if data belongs to start or last node
                if (firstDataPtr == head)
                    head = secondDataPtr;
                else if (secondDataPtr == head)
                    head = firstDataPtr;

                if (firstDataPtr == last)
                    last = secondDataPtr;
                else if (secondDataPtr == last)
                    last = firstDataPtr;

                Node<T> nextFirstDataPtr = firstDataPtr.next;
                Node<T> nextSecondDataPtr = secondDataPtr.next;

                prevFirstDataPtr.next = secondDataPtr;
                secondDataPtr.next = nextFirstDataPtr;

                prevSecondDataPtr.next = firstDataPtr;
                firstDataPtr.next = nextSecondDataPtr;

                // if items belongs to adjacent node
                if (prevSecondDataPtr == firstDataPtr)
                    secondDataPtr.next = firstDataPtr;
                else if (prevFirstDataPtr == secondDataPtr)
                    firstDataPtr.next = secondDataPtr;

                display(head);

            } else
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Either " + firstData + " or " + secondData + " not in the list!");
        }

        public Node<T> reverse(Node<T> link) {
            if (link == null)
                return null;

            if (link.next == null)
                return link;

            Node<T> secondElement = link.next;
            link.next = null;
            Node<T> reverseRest = reverse(secondElement);
            secondElement.next = link;
            return reverseRest;
        }

        public void setHeadandLastLink() {
            Node<T> temp = head;
            head = last;
            last = temp;
            display(head);
        }

        public T middle() {
            if (empty())
                throw new NoSuchElementException("List is empty!");

            Node<T> slowPtr = head;
            Node<T> fastPtr = head;
            while (fastPtr != null && fastPtr.next != null) {
                slowPtr = slowPtr.next;
                fastPtr = fastPtr.next.next;
            }
            return slowPtr.data;
        }

        public int getOccurence(T data, int occurence, Node<T> link) {

            if (empty())
                throw new NoSuchElementException("List is Empty!");

            if (link == null)
                return occurence;

            if (link.data == data) {
                ++occurence;
            }

            return getOccurence(data, occurence, link.next);
        }

        public boolean empty() {
            return head == null;
        }

    }

    public class LinkedListTest {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to Singly Linked List");
            LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            boolean yes = true;
            do {
                System.out.println("\n1. Insert at Begining");
                System.out.println("2. Insert at End");
                System.out.println("3. Insert at any position");
                System.out.println("4. Delete at Position");
                System.out.println("5. Get Size");
                System.out.println("6. Display");
                System.out.println("7. Empty Status ");
                System.out.println("8. Replace data at given position");
                System.out.println("9. Get Element by Position");
                System.out.println("10. Search Element Recursively");
                System.out.println("11. Swap only data not node");
                System.out.println("12. Swap node for given data");
                System.out.println("13. Reverse the list");
                System.out.println("14. Find Middle Element");
                System.out.println("15. Count Occurence of a Number");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                int choice = scanner.nextInt();
                switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    try {
                        linkedList.insertAtFirst(scanner.nextInt());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    try {
                        linkedList.insertAtLast(scanner.nextInt());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Enter position");
                        int position = scanner.nextInt();
                        if (position < 1 || position > linkedList.size()) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid Position!");
                            break;
                        }
                        linkedList.insertAtPosition(position, scanner.nextInt());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                    try {
                        int position = scanner.nextInt();
                        if (position < 1 || position > linkedList.size()) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid position !");
                            break;
                        }
                        linkedList.delete(position);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 5:
                    try {
                        System.out.println(linkedList.size());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 6:
                    try {
                        linkedList.display(linkedList.head);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 7:
                    try {
                        System.out.println(linkedList.empty());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 8:
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Enter position : ");
                        int position = scanner.nextInt();
                        if (position < 1 || position > linkedList.size()) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid Position!");
                            break;
                        }
                        linkedList.replace(position, scanner.nextInt());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 9:
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Enter Position : ");
                        int position = scanner.nextInt();
                        if (position < 1 || position > linkedList.size()) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid Position !");
                            break;
                        }
                        System.out.println(linkedList.elementByPosition(position, linkedList.head, 1));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 10:
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Enter the item to Find it's position : ");
                        int data = scanner.nextInt();
                        System.out.println(linkedList.searchElement(data, linkedList.head, 1));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 11:
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Enter the items to swap");
                        int firstData = scanner.nextInt();
                        int secondData = scanner.nextInt();
                        linkedList.swapData(firstData, secondData);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 12:
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Enter the Data to swap Node");
                        int firstData = scanner.nextInt();
                        int secondData = scanner.nextInt();
                        linkedList.swapNode(firstData, secondData);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 13:
                    try {
                        linkedList.reverse(linkedList.head);
                        linkedList.setHeadandLastLink();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 14:
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Middle Element is : " + linkedList.middle());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 15:
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Enter the item to get Occurence");
                        int data = scanner.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Occurence is : " + linkedList.getOccurence(data, 0, linkedList.head));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
            } while (yes);
        }
    }
```